# Sbt Remote Caching Looses Some Data

Tags: sbt, sbt-plugin

I am trying to use [Sbt Remote Caching](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Remote-Caching.html) with [Sbt Scoverage](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage) that generates a test coverage report. The problem is that the data from the coverage report is being lost when the data is being pushed/pulled and I get the following error:

```
  java.io.FileNotFoundException: /runner/_work/flow-service/flow-service/holiday-api-connector/target/scala-2.12/scoverage-data/scoverage.measurements.6e188693-4092-444d-bd50-b2213544dcf8.137 (No such file or directory)
[info]   at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
[info]   at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:293)
[info]   at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:235)
[info]   at java.base/java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:113)
[info]   at scoverage.Invoker$.$anonfun$invoked$1(Invoker.scala:65)
[info]   at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.getOrElseUpdate(HashMap.scala:86)
[info]   at scoverage.Invoker$.invoked(Invoker.scala:65)
[info]   at com.dixa.holidayapi.cron.Util$.createMultipleHolidayJobs(CronJob.scala:88)
[info]   at com.dixa.holidayapi.cron.AsyncUtilTest.$anonfun$new$3(CronJobTest.scala:66)
[info]   at org.scalatest.flatspec.AsyncFlatSpecLike.transformToOutcomeParam$1(AsyncFlatSpecLike.scala:157)
```

Is there a way to include these files in the data that is being cached?